# .NET Core API - HybridModelBinding not working when send List<string> param to GET API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

i am using .net core 3.1 and create a GET api to receive the params which I send.

Here is my controller

```cs
[Route("api")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("test")]
    public IActionResult Get([FromHybrid] GetQuery query)
    {
        var response = await _mediator.Send(command);
        return response.IsSuccess ? (IActionResult)Ok(response.Value.Result) : BadRequest(response.Error);
    }
}
```

GetQuery:

```cs
public class GetQuery{
 public List<string> Types {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}

}
```

And I call the API

http://localhost:5000/api/test?types=youtube&name=google

From the debug mode, I can see the Name passed in as "google", but the types always is "null"

Does this setup get the problem? or the FromHybrid cannot support in this List

Few things that tried:

1. Changed to "FromQuery", then is working fine.
2. Tried call http://localhost:5000/api/test?types[]=youtube&name=google  , still only get null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://github.com/billbogaiv/hybrid-model-binding#model.  It specifically mentions attributing your model class and properties, which you have not done.  I'm not familiar with this library, but I might start there.

Comment: @DavidL Hi actually i already added in Startup.cs, but the main thing only List<string> is not working right now.

Comment: `types[0]=youtube&name=google` - try this

Comment: @Chetan HI, tried with that, but still getting null.

Comment: It worked in my side, I just add the package `HybridModelBinding` or it will have build error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr0iN.png

Comment: @TinyWang may i know which version that you are using? i am using 0.18.0 version.

Comment: @Ben Me too, the latest stable version.

Comment: ok, did you set anything on the startup.cs? Or you could share me the setup that you did? @TinyWang

Comment: I newly created an asp.net core 3.1 api project, and create a new controller, new model, and install 0.18.0 package, and it worked.